# controller on sonataadminbundle

Tags: php, symfony, server, sonata

I've got an error

> Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   FOS\RestBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::__construct(), 0 passed
>   in
>   /usr/home/marekwozniak/domains/titus.marek-wozniak.pl/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php
>   on line 195 and exactly 3 expected

I use SonataAdminBundle
On other server apps run without any errors.

I've got **7.1 PHP version** on both servers.

Cache is cleaned, base was updated.

Openbase_dir was setted correctly.

Comment: Do you have ab example of the failing call you could include?

Comment: admin/prize/list

Comment: i meant your code

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/e8PR0BS6EoI8nfxydH8T/